# Error: "There is no package 'lifestyle' & non-zero exit status of package installation - does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to program a small darts application but when I try to execute the command

```
one.dart <- tidyr::crossing( first = doubles )
```

I get the following error:

> Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> es gibt kein Paket namens ‘lifecycle’
> ("*error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> there is no package ‘lifecycle’*)

When I try to install the package "lifecycle", I get the warning that the package has non-zero exit status.

I already updated R Studio to the newest version. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Install `lifecycle` by using `install.packages("lifecycle", dependencies = T)`.

Comment: this unfortunately just yields the same error

Comment: Maybe is another package missing. What is the complete message when you try to install the package lifecycle ?